# understanding "independent" term in "independent and identically distributed" (iid) statement

Tags: independence, assumptions, iid

I understand **independent** as the random variable values in a data aren't connected to each other in any way.

**(q1)** Is my understanding ok?

data_1: a product which has a design defect has been sold to different countries. **(q2)** If I collect failure times (assume that all failures are because of the design defect) for those sold products, are my failure times independent or are they dependent because of the design defect?

data_2: a mature, thoroughly tested product's failure times data from independent customers. **(q3)**  Are data_2 truly independent? Do these data needs statistical tests for independency assumption validation?

thanks

Comment: Re q1: "Not connected in any way" is a *heuristic,* not a definition.  Independence has several different but equivalent definitions.  Which one are you using?  The rest of your question concerns *modeling choices* you might make for investigating failure times.  The answers depend on those choices as well as your objectives.

Comment: A def. says "*Two events are independent if the occurrence of one event does not affect the chances of the occurrence of the other event.*" so my q2's answer seems like *they're independent*; right? failure in country A has nothing to do with the failure in country B.

Comment: That's not a definition, because "affect" is undefined: it's only a *heuristic* (and not a very accurate one, either, because it suggests some kind of causality underlies a purely probabilistic concept).  Two events are independent if and only if the probability of both (their intersection) is the product of the probabilities of each taken separately: that's a *definition.*

Comment: i should check the quality of my understanding of *definition* term i think. with all my respect i disagree w you. definition makes you understand the phenomenon so you continue. to product (intersection set) is a continuation path since you decided they are independent somehow. it's not a definition to my definition of *definition*. regards.

Comment: As you say, it does look like you should check the meaning of the term *definition* -- what a *definition* is in mathematics, specifically, since probability is a topic in mathematics and the definition of independence is in turn a mathematical one. A definition might not convey any understanding at all (that's a personal thing), it simply needs to unambiguously state what the thing is in mathematical terms. While definition that conveys understanding is more useful/productive than one that does not (in that sense it matters how you express a definition), but that doesn't change what it means.

Comment: Something that helps convey understanding without being complete and unambiguous is not itself a definition, but is nearer, as whuber indicates, to a *heuristic*. He's quite correct about what the definition of independence is; its definition is mathematical, while the things you mentioned are not adequate as definitions for reasons whuber already gave (such as ambiguity). Some books that try to avoid mathematics will occasionally give 'definitions' of terms that are not really definitions because they don't correspond to the actual, mathematical definition.